# Is it possible to change a Winforms combobox to disable typing into it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So that it just allows selecting items already inside, but not allow typing/editing the text inside it?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Set `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`.

Comment: Since googling for "powershell combobox disable typing" brought me here, here's how this looks in powershell: `$cmb_parent_search_results.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;`

Answer (score 12):

After trying ShaneFulmer's answer, I noticed that the style of the drop down was changed. This was a problem for me and apparently there is no good way of changing it. (Background color doesn't actually change it.)

I ended up adding a keypress handler to prevent adding text.

```
private void myCombo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Why does this actually prevent text being added?

Comment: @AugustWilliams It flags the event as handled before it is sent to the operating system for processing. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note that this doesn't prevent the user from (for example) modifying the ComboBox content by right-clicking and pasting, etc.  Mouse input and other avenues of modification have to be covered separately.

Comment: @Steverino How would you prevent the user from entering contents via the mouse into the `TComboBox`?